# How to use the miscrosoft graph mail api instead of default magento mail?

Tags: magento2, api, order-email, send-mail

I need to use the Microsoft Graph Mail API for each and every Magento email like new customer and order mail. Something like by-pass the default Magento email feature with Microsoft Graph API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For MS graph mail need to use php library class.
composer require microsoft/microsoft-graph

Please the refer the below link. That module using similar method. You need to intercept the email transport class and add your MS graph api call.

https://github.com/ebizmarts/magento2-mandrill-smtp